# Simple Socket Listener and Threads Memory Leak

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets, memory-leaks

I have a simple C program that's supposed to listen for connections and start a new thread for each client that connects. The thread simply prints what messages it receives (for now). I followed two tutorials while making this.

It works, but I tried connecting and disconnecting repeatedly with netcat without sending any messages. Each time I connect, the program takes 8KB of memory, but it only releases 4KB when I disconnect. But I can't find the cause of the leak. It ends the thread and closes the socket every time the user disconnects. Here is all of the code involved:

```
void* clientFunction(void* arg) {
    char receiveBuffer[RECEIVE_BUFFER_SIZE];
    long receiveSize;
    int clntSocket = * ((int*) arg);

    while (true) {
        //receive messages
        receiveSize = recv(clntSocket, receiveBuffer, RECEIVE_BUFFER_SIZE, 0);

        if (receiveSize <= 0) {
            close(clntSocket);
            return NULL;
        }

        printf("Received message: %s", receiveBuffer);
        memset(&receiveBuffer, 0, sizeof(receiveBuffer));
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    //FOR LISTENING SOCKET =====
    int servSock;                    /* Socket descriptor for server */
    int clntSock;                    /* Socket descriptor for client */
    struct sockaddr_in serverAddress; /* Local address */
    struct sockaddr_in clientAddress; /* Client address */
    unsigned int clntLen;            /* Length of client address data structure */
    // =======

    /* Create socket for incoming connections */
    if ((servSock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0) {
        printf("Socket creation failed!\n");
        return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }

    memset(&serverAddress, 0, sizeof(serverAddress));   /* Zero out structure */
    serverAddress.sin_family = AF_INET;                /* Internet address family */
    serverAddress.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); /* Any incoming interface */
    serverAddress.sin_port = htons(PORT);      /* Local port */

    if (bind(servSock, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddress, sizeof(serverAddress)) < 0) {
        printf("Socket binding failed!\n");
        return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }

    if (listen(servSock, MAXPENDING) < 0) {
        printf("Socket listening failed!\n");
        return SOCKET_ERROR;
    }

    isListening = true;
    int* arg = &clntSock;

    while (isListening) { //should have a timer?
        /* Set the size of the in-out parameter */
        clntLen = sizeof(clientAddress);

        /* Wait for a client to connect */
        if ((clntSock = accept(servSock, (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddress, &clntLen)) >= 0) { //??????
            /* clntSock is connected to a client! */
            pthread_t clientThread;
            pthread_create(&clientThread, NULL, &clientFunction, (void*) arg);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Looks like you might need a call to pthread_detach.

Comment: How are you assessing that there is a leak? It might be that some underlying system is not (yet) giving up on some memory, which it may reuse later on. You can see this happening on a simple `malloc` followed by a `free`. The best test would be to run the program for a while, and see if you get a linear increase in memory usage when making N connections per minute.

Comment: OK, I'll try the long-term running test. I wasn't aware that it would do that.

Comment: 500 - Internal Server Error is also correct.  By default those threads are joinable and holding some resources.  Either join or detach them.

Comment: Ah, yes, that is the solution. 500 - Internal Server Error, since you answered first, you can put that as an answer I can mark if you want the points. I put in pthread_detach(pthread_self()) right after the socket closing line, and it doesn't have the problem anymore.

Comment: I also tried leaving it a lot of time to give the memory back without detaching the thread, but it didn't ever give it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put in pthread_detach(pthread_self()) right after the socket closing line, and it doesn't have the problem anymore. – sudo